# FMDB stringforcolumn with nil

Tags: ios, swift3, fmdb

I apologize if this question was asked before (couldn't find an exact solution) but I have a column on my database table that is of type varchar and is nullable.

When I query to get back the column:

```
 let rs: FMResultSet = db.executeQuery("SELECT InternalNote from MyTable where id = ?", withArgumentsIn: [id])

        while(rs.next())
        {
           let testValue = rs.string(forColumn: "InternalNote") 
            ..code continues..
        }
..
```

it causes a crash on the rs.string above because the field is null..

I figured I'll have to just change it to be non-null and default of "", but is there a way I can keep it null?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share with us, what are you trying in order to help you?

Comment: sure added some more code. thanks.

Comment: maybe is a mistake but your `FMResultSet` is named `rsTemp` and not `rs` so maybe is there your problem, please let me know

Comment: hey sorry I just changed some of my code to simplify it but this is basically what I have now and it's crashing.

Comment: Again check the name of your `FMResultSet` and also check if you have other object with name `rs` in your method scope, maybe you have another object named rs and not have the .string method and this is causing your crash

Comment: can you share your crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you change your code to:

```
if let value = rs.string(forColumn: "internalNote") {
    let testValue = value 
    ... code continues ...
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, let me try this.

Comment: Keep me posted :)

Comment: ah the only problem is i'm using it in the constructor. Think I should use a ternary operator? The thing is, I think it's FMDB that crashes unwrapping a null but i'll try

Answer (score 0):

Check that the issue isn't due to the fact that your query has `InternalNote` while your `rs.string(forColumn:)` call has `internalNote`.

Comment: ah sorry just stupid on my part, it's correct in the code. but still no luck